# AngularFire: How to $watch on child of an object?

Tags: angularfire, watch

I want to listen changes done to a particular child of an object.
For ex.
I have data stored in firebase as

```
users: {
  user1:{
    info:{ name: 'Jon', age:'21'},
    otherThings:{}
  },
  user2:{
    info:{ name: 'Mark', age:'20'},
    otherThings:{}
  }
}
```

Now, I can listen to changes in user1 by

```
$scope.userObj = $firebase(userRef).$asObject();
$scope.userObj.$watch(function() {
   console.log("data changed!");
});
```

But is there any way to listen to changes only when its child i.e. $scope.userObj.name changes?

It should be with userObj only, userObj.child('name') or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's $watch command accepts dot notation. Just watch the appropriate field [<kbd>demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/nquy8868/):

```
$scope.$watch('userObj.info.name', callback);
```

Read more in the [$scope docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#scope-life-cycle). This is pretty much Angular 101.

But most likely, this is the wrong approach. Any time you start trying to $watch and manipulate data in the controller, you've probably went down the wrong route. Let the view handle watching, and do data transformations either in a service or (in AngularFire's case) using data transformations like $extendFactory.